# Why won't the array not sort alphabetically?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String file = "";
    Scanner a = null;
    try
    {
        a = new Scanner(new File("names.txt"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("There was an error with your file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(a.hasNextLine())
    {
        file = file +a.nextLine();
        file +="\n";
    }
    System.out.println(file);
    String name [] = {file};
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<name.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<name.length;j++)
        {

            if(name[i].substring(0,1).compareTo(name[j].substring(0,1))<0)
            {
                String temp = name[i];
                name[i] = name[j];
                name[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(i = 0;i < name.length;i++)
        System.out.println(name[i]);
```

note: the file's content is as follows:

```
John
Rachel
Peter
Illyana
Erik
Jimmy
Dan
Ken
Guile
Barbara
```

The output is:

```
John
Rachel
Peter
Illyana
Erik
Jimmy
Dan
Ken
Guile
Barbara

John
Rachel
Peter
Illyana
Erik
Jimmy
Dan
Ken
Guile
Barbara
```

**I'm using OS X, can that be the source of the problem?

Comment: You seem to expect the routine to read out an array of names, but for that to happen you have to actually put newlines in the file. If you were using an old Mac OS, it could have been a problem, because it used to use \r for line ending by default instead of \n (linux, modern Mac OS) or \r\n (Windows). Your code just seems to read all names in a single line, so it doesn't have anything to sort.

Comment: Looks like you have only one item in the array: a single string with new lines in it.  When you sort an array with a single item, you get the same array as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String name [] = {file};`
You just initialize the array with one item in it , you just connected names with `\n` ,seems like an array with multi items . You can initialize it like this :
`String name[] = file.split("\n");`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String file = "";
    Scanner a = null;
    try {
        a = new Scanner(new File("E:\\names.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error with your file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<String> name;
    name = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (a.hasNextLine()) {
        file = a.nextLine();
        name.add(file);
        file += "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(file);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < name.size(); j++) {

            if (name.get(i).substring(0, 1)
                    .compareTo(name.get(j).substring(0, 1)) < 0) {
                String temp = name.get(i);
                name.set(i, name.get(j));
                name.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < name.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(name.get(i));
}
```

Use ArrayList instead of String so that you don't have to specify the size to initialize.

The above code is working. You can make modifications if required.